# Trigger in Doctrine Migrations

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

I am trying to create a rather complex trigger in a doctrine migrations class:

https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/audit-trigger/blob/master/audit.sql

The first impulse was just to put the whole trigger code in one big blob and add it

with:

```
public function up(Schema $schema)
{
    $this->addSql($triggerSqlInABigBlob);
}
```

However the migration fails

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement
```

Is this even possible to manage in a doctrine migration? Is there a workaround / best practice to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addSql` in Doctrine's `AbstractMigration` expects one SQL command or array of multiple SQL commands. What you send is a string containig multiple SQL commands, which is not allowed. You can try this:

```
public function up(Schema $schema)
{
    $this->addSql(explode(';',$triggerSqlInABigBlob));
}
```

That should convert the string into an array where each element is one SQL command. The comments might a problem though.

Comment: This does not solve OP's problem. Though what you are saying is correct, adding  a trigger IS a single statement that might contain statement separators (";"). The `split()` result would be wrong, but even splitting it correctly would not allow doctrine to successfully do a `CREATE TRIGGER` for a trigger that contains separators.

Comment: @istepaniuk I think this exactly solved the OP's problem, or at least the first problem - error `cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement`, the fact that the SQL file contained a trigger was besides the point at the time of writing (4 yrs ago). You would get the same error if you called `$this->addSql('SELECT 1; SELECT 1;');` that was my point.